# SVG Polygon Shape with Image

Tags: javascript, css, svg, polygon

I am trying to make polygon shape for Mozilla with the help of clip path. but I am not able to make it, Below are my code for the circle shape how to change the circle into polygon.

```
<style>
img {clip-path: url(#clipping);}
</style>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
    <circle cx="284" cy="213" r="213" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="img/1.jpg" width="568">
```

{Updated my Question}
Now I have created a polygon but Chrome is not supporting it... how to resolve that... below are my code for polygon it's working on Mozilla.

```
<style>
#img {clip-path: url(#clipping);
      -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
      -webkit-shape-outside: url(#clipping);
       shape-outside: url(#clipping);
}
</style>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
<!--      <circle cx="284" cy="213" r="213" />-->
    <path d="M188 0 L1 0 L1 188 L188 0 Z">
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="img">
<img src="img/1.jpg" width="568">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change cirle into polygon, for polygon, use `path` tag and its `d` attribute. Here's a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) that can help.

Comment: I have updated my question, with your help I design a triangle polygon shape.

Answer (score 2):

Hi The Problem is resolve now.

```
<style>
#img {clip-path: url(#clipping);
      -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
      -webkit-shape-outside: url(#clipping);
       shape-outside: url(#clipping);
}
</style>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
   <clipPath id="clipping">
<!--      <circle cx="284" cy="213" r="213" />-->
    <path d="M188 0 L1 0 L1 188 L188 0 Z">
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div id="img">
<img src="img/1.jpg" width="568">
</div>
```

Thank you for the support